# how C_CreateObject , C_GenerateKey and C_GenerateKeyPair are different ?

Tags: pkcs#11

Our PKCS#11 library miss the implementation of C_CreateObject. Before jumping into its implementation, i want to know the instances where C_CreateObject should be used instead of C_GenerateKey/C_GenerateKeyPair .

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here

Answer (score 5):

`C_CreateObject`imports existing data objects, certificates and/or keys generated externally into the device. `C_GenerateKey` generates new symmetric key (DES/AES/...) inside the device. `C_GenerateKeyPair` generates new asymmetric key pair (RSA/ECC/...) inside the device.

Answer (score 1):

The PKCS#11 treats the Key Pairs (Public Key and Private Key), Certificates and Secret Keys as objects on the token. And there is also a Data Object which just holds some data.

The `C_GenerateKey` would create a `Secret Key` Object.

The `C_GenerateKeyPair` would create a `Public Key` and a `Private Key` Object (both the public key and private key combined would constitute the key pair).

When you say `C_GenerateKey` the PKCS#11 knows that it has to generate a Secret Key Object and expects a Secret Key Object Template. And similarly the `C_GenerateKeyPair`, it knows that it has to create a Public Key Object and a Private Key Object and expects their respective object templates.

But when you say`C_CreateObject`, you have to specify which type of object you want to create, and pass in the right Object Template as well. Consider this like an abstract version of the `C_GenerateXXX` method.