# pkcs#11 CKR_DEVICE_REMOVED error logging in to HSM

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm, opensc

I have the SmartCard HSM usb plugged in to my laptop. I can see it when I run a command thru an application using the PKCS#11 API:

```
Slot 0

    Slot info:
        Description:      Identiv uTrust 3512 SAM slot Token [CCID Interface] (55511725602
        Manufacturer ID:  Identiv                         
        Hardware version: 2.2
        Firmware version: 0.0
        Token present:    yes
    Token info:
        Manufacturer ID:  www.CardContact.de              
        Model:            PKCS#15 emulated
        Hardware version: 24.13
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Serial number:    DECC0300697     
        Initialized:      yes
        User PIN init.:   yes
        Label:            UserPIN (SmartCard-HSM)
```

Its been initialized with a SO-PIN and USER-PIN.

When I try to login in to the HSM using `C_Login`, I get a `CKR_DEVICE_REMOVED` error back. The usb HSM is still plugged in. I have googled the error but nothing fruitful came up.

```
login_token -LOGIN user -SLOT 0 -UPIN user-pin

EROR: rv=0x00000032: Could not log in on the token.
```

How can I login to the HSM ?

Comment: If I ignore the CKR_DEVICE_REMOVED error on C_Login, it passes and generates a key pair. Is it okay to ignore the error or should I be worried about it ?

Comment: Which PKCS#11 library are you using? One provided as a part of OpenSC project?

Comment: Yes - /usr/local/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so

Answer (score 2):

Following text is the description of `CKR_DEVICE_REMOVED` error from [PKCS#11 v2.20 specification](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/tree/master/v2.20):

> `CKR_DEVICE_REMOVED`: The token was removed from its slot during the
>   execution of the function.

If you did not attach/detach new reader and did not insert/remove smartcard once the PKCS#11 library was loaded then I don't see any obvious reason why you are receiving this error.

However you are using PKCS#11 library provided by [OpenSC project](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC) so you can enable its debugging via [environment variable](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Using-OpenSC#debug-level) or [configuration file](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Security-Considerations#debug--debug_file). You may be able to find the cause of the error by exploring the debug output yourself. If not, then your best bet is to open [new OpenSC issue](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/issues/new) and discuss your problem with OpenSC project members.

Comment: Thanks @jariq! I will do that. On a separate note - Can I store an application key in a HSM i.e can I feed a random key to some PKCS#11 function and have it store in the HSM ? Then retrieve it from the HSM using a corresponding 'get' function in PKCS ?

Comment: @ejohnson See [my previous answer to an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43092643/3325704).

Comment: So it seems I can use a C_GenerateKey to generate a AES secret key and that stores the key on the HSM. I can then do a C_FindObject to get the key and its value. It appears C_CreateObject is not necessary here. Am I correct in my understanding ? @jariq

Comment: @ejohnson most likely not the answer you were expecting but you can do literally anything PKCS#11 API allows you to do. Whether it is the best and most secure solution is completely different question and almost impossible to answer without knowing your environment/solution/etc.